# Pass by reference with strings in C

Tags: c

I'm not 100% sure as to how to use pass by reference with strings in C, this is my current code (the rest is not very important just the void function and the calling are giving me issues):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

// global constants
#define MAX 100
#define SIZE 50

void reader(int *count, char *names[SIZE][MAX], char *pax[SIZE][MAX], char *range[SIZE][MAX], char *cost[SIZE][MAX])
{
    char line[SIZE]; 
    FILE *filepointer;
    filepointer = fopen("planedata.txt", "r");
    *count = 0;
    while(fgets(line, SIZE, filepointer) != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(*names[*count], line); 
        if(fgets(line, SIZE, filepointer) != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(*pax[*count], line);
        }
        if(fgets(line, SIZE, filepointer) != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(*range[*count], line);
        }
        if(fgets(line, SIZE, filepointer) != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(*cost[*count], line);
        }
        *count++;
    }
    fclose(filepointer);
}
```

I've tried removing asterisks and other things but it just doesn't work, I think it may be something to do with the fact that I'm using arrays in my declaration, but I'm not really sure. Any help would be appreciated. 
This is where I call the void function if it helps:

```
reader(&count, &names[SIZE][MAX], &pax[SIZE][MAX], &range[SIZE][MAX], &cost[SIZE][MAX]);
```

Comment: You need to use c++ to pass by reference.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen that isn't happening?

Comment: C does not have pass by reference: function arguments are always passed by value.  But you can pass a pointer (by value), by which the called function can manipulate the pointed-to object.

Comment: What is the expected type for the arguments to this function?  You said "strings", which probably means `char *`, but it looks like you may actually be expecting *arrays* of `char *`.  Or 2D arrays of `char`, which would be importantly different.

Comment: `char *names[MAX][SIZE]` and `strcpy(names[*count], line);` makes more sense.  Need a [mcve].

Comment: "it just doesn't work" attracts down-votes.  Instead, make clear expected output and report output seen and a [mcve].